# Class diagram for android gallery

Tags: android, architecture, gallery, class-diagram

I'm working on an android project. My reference source code is android gallery app. I want to create a user interface like that. But i found it difficult to understand and analyse the gallery app code. Is there a 'Class diagram' or 'Architecture' of gallery app available ?

Can anyone please suggest me a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of one, but you could use something like http://www.objectaid.com/ to produce one from the [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/camera/gallery/).

Comment: I think it will be useful for me. I will try with this.